# Ambiguous call Math.Round ( int64 / int64, int)

Tags: c#, double, decimal, rounding, ambiguous

I would like to do percentage with large number (int64 : 600 851 475 143)

My actual operation is

```
a = Math.round(i / 600851475143 * 100, 5);
```

With i also an int64 between 1 and 600851475143. The result will be between 0,00000% and 100,00000% if i'm right.

But Visual Studio Express 2013 say me that ambiguous call between methods 'System.Math.Round(decimal, int)' and 'System.Math.Round(double, int)'.

How to say to visual that the good methods is System.Math.Round(decimal, int) even if some int64 are in the operation ?

Bonus :
To understand my problem, i'm trying to solve ProjectEuler.net's problem 3 :
"The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?"

I did my method and it works with 13195. But now i have to do it with 600851475143 (on x64 system), but my algo seems not to be optimezed and i would like to add an percentage progress bar to know if my EXE crash or not. My a var is this percentage...

I DON'T WANT THE ANSWER of Euleur problem 3, i just need to fix my percentage issue...

Comment: Hint: the largest prime factor of any number cannot be larger than its square root. (Do you see why?)  So you can stop looking for factors when you get to the square root of that number; you don't need to go all the way to the number itself.

Comment: And an additional hint: as soon as you've found a prime factor, you can divide your number by that prime factor. You then need to search only to the square root of the new smaller number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marking the numeric value with an `M` after it will make it a decimal value. And use the correct overload for Round.

```
var a = Math.Round(i / 600851475143M * 100, 5);
```

Answer (score 6):

If `i` is an integer then the quotient is zero or one, because an integer divided by an integer is always an integer in C#. You meant to say

```
a = Math.round(i / 600851475143.0 * 100.0, 5);
```

Which forces the calculation to be in doubles, or

```
a = Math.round(i / 600851475143.0m * 100.0m, 5);
```

Which forces it to be in decimals.

The error message is correct -- it is ambiguous whether the integer result should be converted to decimal or double. It's just not pointing out the more fundamental error.

Incidentally, this error is extremely common. So common in fact that my team is working on a static analyzer to detect it.  A now-deleted answer actually gave a form of the error that I see quite frequently:

```
a = Math.round((decimal)(i / 600851475143 * 100), 5);
```

That removes the ambiguity -- clearly you meant the `decimal` overload -- but the calculation is done in integers, rounded to integers, and *then* converted to decimal!  If you're going to put in a cast it has to be on one of the *operands*, not on the *result*.

Comment: Of course, OP could also do `a = Math.round(i / 6008514751.43, 5);`

Comment: @KrisVandermotten That would not use the decimal overload.

Comment: @Magnus I never said it would. It would use the `double` overload. What is wrong with that?

Comment: By modifying to 600851475143M Visual don't notify me an error. I think it's the good answer.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten: Read the question again.

Comment: @EricLippert I See. Didn't see that first time. Anyway, he could do `a = Math.Round(i / 6008514751.43m, 5);` then.